# How to delete service zookeeper from ambari?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, ambari

I am using this command to delete service from ambari:

```
 curl -u admin:admin -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X DELETE  http://192.168.24.226:8080/api/v1/clusters/zwlbs/services/Zookeeper
```

response:

```
{
  "status" : 404,
  "message" : "org.apache.ambari.server.controller.spi.NoSuchResourceException: The specified resource doesn't exist: Service not found, clusterName=zwlbs, serviceName=ZOOKEEPER_SERVER"
}
```

I've aready tried:

```
curl -u admin:admin -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X DELETE  http://192.168.24.226:8080/api/v1/clusters/zwlbs/services/Zookeeper_Service

curl -u admin:admin -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X DELETE  http://192.168.24.226:8080/api/v1/clusters/zwlbs/services/ZOOKEEPER
```

What can i do to delete ZooKeeper service?The service is aready installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the service name is UPPERCASE:

```
curl -u admin:admin -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X DELETE  http://192.16824.226:8080/api/v1/clusters/zwlbs/services/ZOOKEEPER
```